# Is RAM always readable

Tags: ram

I am currently interfacing with a temperature sensor (MLX90616) which stores data in certain ram addresses which can be accessed.
I am interested in looking at the raw IR data as opposed to the calculated object or ambient temperature. This would involve accessing addresses 0x004 and 0x005 which have not been indicated as readable on the table below from the datasheet.

my question therefore is if RAM always readable? or does it depend on the device.
if so why would a manufacture not indicate that these addresses are readable on the datasheet?

[image]

Comment: Is there a publicly-accessible datasheet for this part anywhere? When I try and look for it, they want me to sign up before letting me see it.

Answer (score 6):

The part you're using has an SMBus interface, so the question is not one of whether RAM is readable, but rather whether or not the device will let you read specific addresses.

The answer is that it's entirely up to the design of the specific device, and no general rule applies here. If the datasheet does not list the address as readable, the device may or may not return it if queried - and if it does, that could change at any time with newer revisions.